# Five Boxplots in one ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to make five boxplots of time series (data frame) in one ggplot. Is that possible?

This is how I've done so far, making one at a time and then I can have them side by side with plot_grid.

```
BoxAAPL <- ggplot(oldandnew, aes(y = oldandnew[,2])) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Daily Return %") +
  theme_classic()
```

But is it possible to have them all in one plot? That is for each of: `"AAPL, not cleaned","AAPL, cleaned","GE","SPY","WMT"`? From here http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-box-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization I can see that I should change from numeric to factor but that doesn't really makes sense to me. Maybe because it's times series data?

A data sample:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(10960, 10961, 10962, 10963, 
10966), class = "Date"), `AAPL, not cleaned` = c(-8.810021, 1.45281, 
-9.051401, 4.628075, -1.774445), `AAPL, cleaned` = c(-8.810021, 
1.45281, -9.051401, 4.628075, -1.774445), GE = c(-4.08219945, 
-0.17376199, 1.32681098, 3.7986923, -0.03966156), SPY = c(-3.989133, 
0.1787311, -1.620197, 5.645238, 0.3424661), WMT = c(-3.813763, 
-2.360084, 1.391327, 7.280618, -1.841673)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with `ggplot`, but `ggplot` expects the data to have each observation on its own row of the `data.frame`.

This is the same approach recommended in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61624220/13095326) to one of your previous questions.

Therefore, we need to do some data transformation first. We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to do this, and we can use the `-Date` selection argument to tell it to pivot all columns except `Date`. The defaults move the names of the columns to the `name` column and the values to `value`.

Then we tell `ggplot` to group the values by `name` and change their colors in the `aes` call.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
oldandnew %>%
  pivot_longer(-Date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=value, x=name, fill=name)) +
     geom_boxplot() +
     xlab("") + 
     ylab("Daily Return %") +
     theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure how to interpret the x-axis though?

Comment: If you add an `x=name` mapping to `aes()` it will have more useful x-axis labels. I honestly have no idea how it decides on those otherwise.